# TextWrangler - removing namespaces from XML

Tags: xml, macos, replace, tags, textwrangler

I'm working with TextWrangler's find and replace function. I have a folder of XML files that all include this tag:

```
<song xmlns="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song" version="0.8" createdIn="OpenLP 2.0.1" modifiedIn="OpenLP 2.0.1" modifiedDate="2013-06-23T21:33:21">
```

I would like to remove the namespaces and other info from the tag and get just this:

```
<song>
```

My issue is twofold:

1. First, I can't get TextWrangler to find anything that includes angle brackets. I don't know how to search for a literal angle bracket.
2. The modifiedDate= part of the tag is different for each file. Therefore, I need something that will find all text contained in the tag, no matter what it says.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really worth acquiring sufficient familiarity with XSLT for this kind of task. Doing it in a text editor will always have limitations (for example your code is quite likely to depend on the attributes being in a particular order). It's probably as simple as this:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

This will in fact remove namespaces and attributes from all elements, not just the song element, but this can easily be changed by adding another template rule.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That gets the job done. However, I'd like to use that template in conjunction with another template that actually lays out the style of the XML. I tried putting this template before mine, but now mine doesn't work. How can I use both templates in the same XSLT?

Comment: You can write a pipeline of transformations either as a single stylesheet or as a sequence of separate stylesheets. The second gives better modularity and reuse but is a bit more complex. To do it in a single stylesheet, capture the result of the first template (or transformation) in a variable, and then apply-templates to the variable in a different mode.